# VB.NET to C# string array conversion

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net

Below is my `VB.NET` code which i required to convert to c#

```
Dim lsOTHEROPR as string()
lsOTHEROPR(iArrCnt)(1)
```

Having confusion that how to use the (1) after the array index

Comment: I do not know VB that much but I can suppose that this is a char, so it is like:
`strArray[index][1]` this takes the second char in the string

Comment: It's probably an index of a char within the string

Comment: That's not valid VB6 - there is no string indexer, you must mean VB.Net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it into `C#` like this:

```
string[] strArray = new [] { "str", "blah" };
Console.WriteLine(strArray[0][1]); // will return you 't'
```

That `(1)` returns the second character in the string that you select from array with `lsOTHEROPR(iArrCnt)`.